# node.js: Updating an app without the need to stop and run again

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've started playing with node.js and express.js and wrote an hello-world app following the docs:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World');
});
```

If I change the code and refresh the browser - nothing happens.
I have to stop the server and run it again.

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: I don't think so, that's a normal situation, you modify the server side code. If you change the template's code, you don't need to restart the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do have to stop it and start it again.

There are apps that do this automatically for you. Check out nodemon for example: 
https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: also checkout forever and supervisor

Comment: Which of those is the recommended one?

Comment: I use [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) in development and [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) in production.